# How to catch user closed window without logging out of application

Tags: asp.net, webforms

My requirement is user should not log in from multiple browser or system simultaneously in application. For this I maintained the flag in database, so whenever user is logged in I am updating flag as yes and when he logged out I am updating it as no.

My issue is  if user close the browser window without logging out from application then I am unable to update the flag. So next time when user try to logging in application, It is saying user is already logged in.

I tried using Onbeforeunload event in master page, but whenever I am changing the menu in my application. It is firing that event. For updating the flag I used page methods. But this is not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, send often via a ajax call to your API that a 'ping' to confirm you are still online. If there is no ping or page change after 3 minutes, I consider the user has been logged off and it sets him as "logged off" in database.

At least, I do this using javascript, but i'm sure you can also in your client-side part of the ASP.NET app you are making.

Comment: But I think it wont work.
If user has logged in using IE  and closed the browser without logging out. And now trying to logging using Google chrome but he wont be able to logged in as the flag in database is yes. So sending ping wont work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can't handle this only by client-side code, using e.g. `beforeunload`, because the page/browser may be closed for many reasons (e.g. lack of electricity).
What you can do is:

1. Scheduler on your backend which verifies whether an user did some action since e.g. 1min. In that case you have to update information about user action in your DB after every ajax requests ([Hugo Regibo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6103598/hugo-regibo) suggested ping requests).
   Disadvantage od this solution is this period - when an user turns off the page then he will be not able to log in again for 1min.
   Instead of a scheduler you can verify logged-in users (I assume you keep them in a DB table) after each requests.
2. Use web sockets, you will have continuous connection and you will be notified about closed connection immediately. Disadvantage of this is web sockets don't scale so good as stateless HTTP.

Besides that I don't know whether you use iis with a session provider or not? And when an user closes the page and opens it again should be able to log in with his saved credentials. You should write more of how your project looks like.

Comment: you are right. I can't handle it only by client side code. Because I cant catch that event in google chrome.

I am updating flag whenever user logged in or logged off from application in database. So if user closes the page without proper logged out, he wont be able to log in again. For that I provided one option that if user is trying to logging in then I am displaying popup window asking him to logout. But it became very frustrating because most of the time user just closed the browser without logging out properly.

Comment: One more issues is that I have set the session for 30 minutes. So whenever session expired, I am unable to update the flag as I don't know which event will fire once session expires.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it by saving a `Session` object for each login call.  A session ID would then be stored in the user's cookie or authentication token.  Each call to the system would validate the user via their session ID.  If that session has been invalidated, they just get sent to the login prompt.  Whenever the user logs in, it invalidates all of their other sessions.

This way the user could be in their browser on their machine, navigate away, close the browser, and come back to find their session still alive without having to log back in.  *But*, if they log into another machine, then their old session would be invalidated.